# How do I add to a UINavigationController push animation, rather than replace it?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I implemented my own custom animation using the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol. However, this replaces the entire default push animation (including the navigation bar animation, and the new view sliding on top of the old one). I want to keep that stuff, and animate a simple UIView on top, which visualises how an item from the first view is being taken to the next.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "annimateAlongSide" function .... think it belongs to the TransitionCoordinator.  Check that out.

Comment: Works great, thank you! For reference, [here's the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator/animateAlongsideTransition:completion:).